# Вывод подкатегорий на отдельной странице - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать вывод дочерних кастомных таксономий в WordPress?

Например, есть несколько рубрик:
Рубрика1->Подрубрика1->Подподрубрика1->записи
нужно выводить только названия рубрик в виде списка и сделать при клике по ним переходы глубже, пока не дойдем до конкретной коллекции, где выводятся просто посты.

В подрубриках, кроме последней, постов не будет. В них нужно вывести только дочерние подрубрики. А в самой последней подрубрике уже будут записи.

Comment: Где  "вывести"?...

Comment: В кастомной таксономии

Comment: **В** таксономии ничего вывести нельзя. Можно вывести саму таксономи (точнее термы). Так где их выводить? Задача не ясна.

Comment: я создал taxonomy-product.php и там работаю. Получилось вывести вот так:
Categories
aciform
Категории
sub
antiquarianism
Категории
Нет категорий
arrangement
Категории
Нет категорий

Comment: Блин.. Ты бумажжкой на столбе "выводишь"? У меня срок аренды пыточной заканчивается.

Comment: Короче, по умолчанию пустые рубрики не показываются. Или wp_list_categories/get_the_term_list - hide_empty

Answer (score 3):

Как я понял вам необходимо вывести подкатегории текущей категории:

```
$current_term = get_queried_object();

$terms = get_terms( [
    'taxonomy' => [ 'taxonomy_name' ],
    'parent'         => $current_term->term_id,
] );

var_dump( $terms );
```